# Add an additional field for Upfront Fee under Subtotal

Tags: checkout, price

I want to add an additional field (in Magento's built-in cash-on-delivery method) for Upfront Fee right below the Subtotal. This Upfront Fee would be displayed OR calculated ONLY when the subtotal is greater than `$250`. If the subtotal is greater than `$250` this Upfront Fee will get calculated as 20% of whatever the Subtotal amount is i.e >`$250`

> How can i do this>?
>
> Do i need a module or what?

It is one minute game in PHP we just have fetch value,define condition and echo the result but i have no clue about how to do this in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You need module for this case. Creat new quote object to fetch additional field
creat new model extend Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract